# Filter calendar based on userinput

Tags: xslt, calendar, filter, inputformtextbox

Im very new to sharepoint and trying to learn, just so you know :)..Im using Foundation, so please try to give answers that applies to Foundation

Alright so I made a calendar webpart. I can apply som simple text filters. But what if I want a text box, and use the value from the textbox to filter?
the query code in sharepoint designer displays as:

```
<Where>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name="Title"/>
<Value Type="Text">meeting</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>
```

So instead of "meeting" I would like a pointer to a textbox ID or something wich use the value to filter. Is this possible?...If so, could this ID be any textbox? even from another webpart?

That would be awsome since I have a ListViewByQuery web part with a searchbox to display some simple list items, wich works fine. So it would be cool if when I used the search box, the calender would also update based on the textbox value in the ListViewByQuery web part.

But the most important thing here is just to be able to control the filter by user input somehow. in sharepoint designer or visual studio :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can with SharePoint designer. The rendered HTML for the webpart may be what you are looking for. View source and find the ID for the textbox in the webpart. Use that as the filter (in a parameter) in SharePoint Designer to filter in the items you want on the second text box.

Check out:
[Customize Data Views and forms using SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/customize-data-views-and-forms-using-sharepoint-designer-HA101631678.aspx)

Comment: thank for your answer, I did find the button. The ID is quite long compared to what I set in visual studio(buttonID). In view source, its: "ct100_m_g_cad563" and alot of random numbers after that but ends with: "_buttonID"...Also, what parameter source should I use for my filter? ...under "Control" i find a somewwhat similar id to my button..tried that but it didnt work :/

Comment: use the "ct100_m_g_cad563" as your a Control ID.

Comment: Yea I tried that, didnt work..thanks for trying thou

Comment: Try to make the textbox outside of the webpart...